# Does an acquired company also receive the same benefits and pay rates as the parent?

Tags: acquisition

I'm thinking of applying to a company that was recently acquired by a much larger company with much better benefits. Will the benefits also be adapted to the acquired company?

Comment: There are so many variables involved that there is no way to correctly answer this question other than to say maybe.

Comment: 'Maybe' is an answer. Especially if it's possible to say something about likely scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely this is an "it depends".  Over time, it makes sense for companies to combine into one benefits structure, offering benefits competitive with the overall industry and trying to keep all employees in a more or less similar structure.

In the throes of a recent acquisition, however, it's anyone's guess.

Personally, I wouldn't spend a lot of time pre-application worrying over this one.  Submit your resume and make it a question on your first call.

Answer (score 4):

In the UK you keep the benefits you had with your **original** employer in the short to medium term. This is to protect you if the new employer's benefits are "worse". It obviously works both ways in that you don't necessarily get all the "better" benefits they might offer.

How the transition is handled will vary from company to company and from take-over to take-over, but the goal will be to have all the new employees integrated into the main organisation as soon as possible, if for no other reason than it will be easier to manage the company if everyone is operating on the sale rules.

Answer (score 2):

In the US in the short term they won't change. Since most companies handle insurance on a annual contract they can't change in midstream. And because it can take months to work out the rates when switching companies, it can even extend into the next contract period. Some benefits like holiday and vacation are also budgeted for annually.

Moving money between pension or 401K custodians will also take time.

The biggest issue will be if there are any union agreements, these can take a longtime to merge into the new company.

The employees in both companies will be concerned about the merger of the benefits packages. They will assume that the result will be the lesser of each plan will be preserved. Sometimes they end up having to craft a process that takes years to transition. They sometimes make a tiered system. The grandfathered employees get the better pension, new employees don't. Other times that will give lump sum X extra days of vacation to ease the transition.

Keep in mind that any benefit is not forever, and they can change each year. Many companies dropped 401K matching with back in 2008-2009, though some are bringing it back.

When compared to pay, work location, and job description; most parts of the benefits packages are in the noise.